# Обрезать строку после символа

Tags: python, python-2.x

Заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но я видимо заработался и очень сильно туплю...

Допустим есть некая строка (домен) `my-name-1.my.lovely.local` - тут может меняться абсолютно всё (буквы, числа, символы) кроме кол-ва поддоменов (кол-ва точек). Подскажите пожалуйста, как обрезать `.lovely.local` и получить `my-name-1.my` ?

Comment: `s = 'my-name-1.my.lovely.local'
print '.'.join([s.split('.')[0], s.split('.')[1]])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
s = 'my-name-1.my.lovely.local'
parts = s.rsplit('.', 2)  # ['my-name-1.my', 'lovely', 'local']
res = parts[0]  # my-name-1.my
```