# Как правильно обрезать строку начиная с конца до первого с начала заданного символа?

Tags: python, строки

Допустим у меня есть такая строка:

```
a = "Hello:World:OK"
```

Мне нужно обрезать строку, чтобы она выглядела вот так:

```
a = "Hello"
```

То есть, обрезать начиная с конца все символы до первого с начала ":".

Comment: a.split(':')[0]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обрезать строку после символа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711619/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: это у вас первый ":", а не последний

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы в этом случае воспользовался [str.partition()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition), т.к. нам не нужно разбивать строку по двоеточию больше одного (первого) раза:

```
a = a.partition(":")[0]
print(a)
```

или явно указать значение `maxsplit=1` в функции `str.split()`:

```
a = a.split(":", maxsplit=1)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё можно использовать такую конструкцию:

```
s = a[0:a.index(":")]
```

Если символ `:` в строке отсутствует, то случится ошибка.